# Constraint view not updating position after setX

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have 2 views and I'm showing them one below the other one like this(both of them children of the same parent:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#00FF00"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#0000FF"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/view1" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

All works fine but when I change view1 position with setY method the view2 view not updating it's y position too.
I tried to call invalidate and requestLayout, but nothing helps.
How can I refresh or update the constraints after setting the position.

Comment: did you fiugure out a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 2):

This is a little confusing, so bear with me. [`setY()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setY(float)) does the following:

> Sets the visual y position of this view, in pixels. This is equivalent to setting the translationY property to be the difference between the y value passed in and the current top property.

And [`setTranslationY()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTranslationY(float)) does this:

> Sets the vertical location of this view relative to its top position. This effectively positions the object post-layout, in addition to wherever the object's layout placed it.

The key phrase here is "positions the object post-layout." In other words, the view that is the subject of `setY()`is positioned according to the layout then is moved to the new location based upon the argument to `setY()`. This does not result in another layout. In essence, although the view appears in its new location, it is, effectively, still in its original location. Invalidating and requesting another layout just causes the same layout to occur *followed* by the translation.

Setting the top margin as Ben P. suggests should work to move the view.

Comment: Hi, although it's an old post, it is relevant for me :) . I'm curious, can you please explain me, why *topMargin* **affect** view2 and *setX* **doesn't**?

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure why `setY()` doesn't also update the second view, but you can work around it by setting the first view's top margin instead of calling `setY()`:

```
ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams params = 
        (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) view1.getLayoutParams();

params.topMargin = 200;
view1.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

Just move `view1` using `setTranslationY()`, then assign `view1` translationY to `view2`.

Java example:

```
view1.setTranslationY(10f);
view2.setTranslationY(view1.getTranslationY())
```

Kotlin version:

```
view1.translationY = 10f
view2.translationY = view1.translationY
```